# Handle Success and Error of multiple lightning:recordEditForm form submit

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I have multiple lightning:recordEditForm in a lightning component. I have created a single button to submit all those forms. Using the following code.

```
component.find("recordViewForm").forEach( form =>{
        form.submit();    
    });
```

This code is submitting the form but after submission, I want to access its result i.e success or error. I do not find anything regarding this. The **onsuccess** and **onerror** is not working in this case either.

Comment: Multiple edits submitted at once is not an ideal use case. Even if you get it working, it will not perform well, especially on mobile devices.

Comment: @sfdcfox Is there any way I can access these forms and their values. So that I can update them from the server-side(Apex).